# how to update cart items using ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quantity

I need to update quantity of cart items without reloading whole page(using ajax) but with simple code not a lengthy method.
anybody please help me out.

Comment: Which magento version

Comment: magento 1.9 version

Comment: Suggestion to be use  any 3rd  party extension

Comment: Without `a lengthy method.` you  cannot do it

Comment: i need customization without third party extension

Comment: At Cart page? ....

Comment: yes only at cart page and suggest some free extensions too

Comment: If it is not working, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.btn-update').on('click',
        function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('form'));

            // we'll extract the action and method attributes out of the form

            // kick off an ajax request using the form's action and method,
            // with the form data as payload
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                method: form.attr('method'),
                data: form.serializeArray()
            });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: When i am refreshing cart page it's updating cart not on click of "Update" button.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can refer http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/04/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax/ this url or some of the free extension are also available for this like

1) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-popup.html

2) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-add-to-cart-4.html

3) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-mini-cart-ajax-cart.html

4) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-filter-and-cart-1.html

Hope this will help you.